# How do I get a <textarea> value in jQuery to PERMANENTLY be added to the html file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append, textarea

Simply, there is a function on my website which allows users to enter text and have it display on a page.

HOWEVER, that text does not stay permanently and disappears when the page is reloaded.

How do I get jQuery to add the text inserted in the textarea to stay on that page once submitted?

This is what my jQuery looks like.

```
    //When the 'button' is clicked, it prints whatever is in the textarea in separate divs

//this is it:

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#button').click(function() {
    var toAdd = $('textarea[name=input]').val();
    $('.list').append('<div class="posts">' + toAdd + '</div>');
});
});
```

Please ask me if you don't understand me and thank you in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 1):

You would need to send the information to your server and your server would have to modify the actual file on the server's file system. When you load a web page your browser makes a request to your server and asks for the file. Every time you reload, it asks again and the server serves up a fresh copy of the file. The file has to be modified at the source, on your server.

From your question, it's probably safe to say that you have a lot of learning to do, but maybe this example will get you started.

First you need the code on the client-side to send data up to your server:

```
$(function () {
  $('#button').click(function () {
    var toAdd = $('textarea[name=input]').val();
    $.ajax({
      url: '/some/endpoint/on/your/server',
      method: 'POST',
      data: { htmlToAppend: toAdd },
    });
  });
});
```

That uses JQuery to make a [POST request](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)) to your server, and sends the `toAdd` element along with the request.

Next your server needs to be coded to accept that POST request and modify the source of the HTML file. The following code is all JavaScript running on the [Node.js](http://nodejs.org) platform. Node.js is just Google Chrome's JavaScript engine (named [V8](https://developers.google.com/v8/)) running on the server instead of in the browser. JavaScript in the browser has access to a client-side API that lets it control the HTML that is loaded into the browser at that moment, which is what you are doing by appending that `<div>` to your page. JavaScript in node has access to a server-side API that lets it perform actions on your server.

If you don't know node.js don't worry, this just an example to demonstrate what you need on the server side of things. Any server-side language/technology will work here, it just needs to perform actions similar to this:

```
// Think of these require calls like <script src=""></script>
// references in node. The "http", "fs", and "querystring"
// modules are both modules built into node.js.
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs'); // fs stands for File System.
var qs = require('querystring');

// You can get tons of modules from the community
// using the npm registry. Cheerio is one of them.
// I did "npm install cheerio" from the root of my project.
// Cheerio is basically JQuery that you can use on the
// server to manipulate an HTML file.
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

// Create an http server to listen for requests.
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  // If the request was made to the root of our site, serve our
  // html file.
  if (request.url === '/') {
    // Read html file from hard drive.
    var htmlFile = fs.readFileSync('./path/to/html/file.html');
    // Respond to the user with a 200 status code telling the
    // browser that the request was successful.
    response.writeHead(200);
    // Write the html file's contents to the response stream.
    response.write(htmlFile, 'binary');
    // Close the response stream.
    response.end();
  }
  else if (request.url.toLowerCase() === '/some/endpoint/on/your/server') {
    // Declare a variable to build our request body.
    var requestBody = '';
    // Whenever the request stream receives data, append
    // it to requestBody.
    request.on('data', function (data) {
      requestBody += data;
    });
    // When the request is finally complete, run our code to
    // modify the actual HTML file.
    request.on('end', function () {
      // Use the querystring module to parse the requestBody
      // into a JavaScript object similar to the one we passed
      // to JQuery's ajax method on the client-side.
      var post = qs.parse(requestBody);
      // Read the contents of our HTML file into memory.
      var htmlFile = fs.readFileSync('./path/to/html/file.html');
      // Load the html file into Cheerio so we can manipulate it
      // jquery style :)
      var $ = cheerio.load(htmlFile);
      // Append the htmlToAppend from the request body to the
      // bottom of the .list element.
      $('.list').append(post.htmlToAppend);
      // Render the HTML document out of Cheerio and into a string.
      var newHtmlFile = $.html();
      // Write the modified document back to the hard drive.
      fs.writeFileSync('./path/to/html/file.html', newHtmlFile);
      // End the response so the user's browser doesn't hang waiting
      // waiting for a response from the server. Ideally you'd send
      // down some data that your client-side jquery can use to
      // display a friendly message to the user.
      response.end();
    })
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There really is not a lot information to go on, but you could also use localstorage, read the values after page load, and set the text/values.

http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/04/how-to-use-local-storage-for-javascript/

But personally, I would go with Chev idea unless there was some special requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use HTML5 local storage and that's enough, than it can be simple.

```
window.localStorage.setItem("name", value);
window.localStorage.getItem("name");
```

See JsFiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ddan/yftxoboy/5/).